# how to show the progress Dialog in Android?

Tags: android

I need to show the progress Message to the user.But i can't able to show that.Here is my code.What's wrong in my code.Guide me to do.

```
public class MyProgressDemo extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

private Button clickBtn;
public ProgressDialog progressDialog;
Handler handler = new Handler();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    clickBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
    clickBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MyProgressDemo.this, "",
                    "Please Wait");
            processThread();

        }

    });

}

protected void processThread() {

    handler.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            longTimeMethod();
            UI();
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

}

private void longTimeMethod() {
    try {
        String strMethod = "MethodName";
        String strUrl = "url";
        String strResponse = WebserviceCall.Mobileaappstore(strUrl,
                strMethod);
        Log.d("RES", strResponse);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Exc", e.getMessage());
    }

}

private void UI() {
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText("This is new UI");
    setContentView(tv);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method Handler.post, spawn a thread within the UI thread, so your longTimeMethod(); will be run in the UI thread, blocking it so. You should do it like this:

```
protected void processThread() {
    Thread t = new Thread(){
       longTimeMethod();
       // Sends message to the handler so it updates the UI
       handler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(mHandler, THREAD_FINISHED));
    }
    // Spawn the new thread as a background thread
    t.start
}
```

Your handler should look like this in order to manage the message

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);

            switch (msg.what) {
            case THREAD_FINISHED:
                       UI();
                       progressDialog.dismiss();
                       break    
                }   
        }
};
```

You can use either this solution or AsynTask, it's up to you, both work. Choose the one that best adapts to you.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do perfectly fits the [AsyncTask framework](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) in Android. Try to implement it by subclassing the AsyncTask class, taking care of putting all UI related stuff in the onPreExecute/onPostExecute methods and you long time method in the doInBackground method.

If you need stuff from the activity, either pass it as a parameter in the constructor of the AsyncTask or have your AsyncTask as an inner class of the activity.

Answer (score 0):

To add to MarvinLabs' post, you can show and dismiss the ProgressDialog like this.

```
private class SubmitCommentTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        // Your long running code here
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(DetailsInfo.this, "Submitting Comment", "Please wait for the comment to be submitted.", true);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void Result)
    {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```